# WebRTC peer to nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I would like to use webRTC but instead of p2p would like to broadcast my audio/video feed to nodejs in realtime. I can encode the video to 125 kbps and 10-12 frames per second for smooth transmission. The idea is nodejs will receive this feed, save it and broadcast it on the same time as a realtime session/webinar. I can connect p2p but I am not sure how to

1. send feed to nodejs instead of peer
2. on nodejs how to receive feed

Comment: You need a network component  called a "multipoint control unit", "selective forwarding unit," or "bridge." https://gist.github.com/jpopesculian/a19bd79481000e12dc9d

Comment: This is very heplful, thankyou. The problem is most of these platforms are outdated. I am having hard time to find someone with active development. Is it possible to transmit the stream to server using sockets instead? I mean it is posisble but is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The WeRTC protocol suite is complex enough that an implementation from scratch for a selective forwarding unit SFU is likely to take at least a year by a team of experts. It requires handling a variety of networking protocols including datagrams (UDP) and TCP. And it may require transcoding between video and audio codecs.

The good news is that browser endpoints are now excellent.  And open-source server implementations are good enough to get to a minimum viable product.

Comment: Thank you, could you suggest some open-source server that can be implemented to make it possible please? A way forward will be highly appreciated.